# No view Manager defined for class RCTMap

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to use the `MapView` for Android with react-native. Here is my (very basic) code :

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  View,
  ToastAndroid,
  MapView,
  ToolbarAndroid
} = React;

var SwitchAndroid = require('SwitchAndroid');

var toolbarActions = [
  {title: 'Create', icon: require('image!ic_create_black_48dp'), show: 'always'},
  {title: 'Filter'},
  {title: 'Settings', icon: require('image!ic_settings_black_48dp'), show: 'always'},
];
var velib = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      actionText: 'Example app with toolbar component',
      toolbarSwitch: false,
      colorProps: {
        titleColor: '#3b5998',
        subtitleColor: '#6a7180',
      },
    };
  },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <View>
                 <ToolbarAndroid
                    actions={toolbarActions}
                    navIcon={require('image!ic_menu_black_24dp')}
                    onActionSelected={this._onActionSelected}
                    onIconClicked={() => this.setState({actionText: 'Icon clicked'})}
                    style={styles.toolbar}
                    subtitle={this.state.actionText}
                    title="Toolbar" 
                />
                <MapView
                    showsUserLocation="true"
                />
            </View>
        )
    },
    onActionSelected: function(position) {
      if (position === 0) { // index of 'Settings'
        showSettings();
      }
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: '#e9eaed',
    height: 56,
  },
   map: {
    height: 150,
    margin: 10,
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderColor: '#000000',
  },
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('velib', () => velib);
```

But I always get this error :

[image: No view Manager defined for class RCTMap]

Here are my logcat errors :

```
W/ReactNativeJS(18572): 'Warning: Native component for "RCTModalHostView" does not exist'
W/ReactNativeJS(18572): 'Warning: Native component for "RCTTextView" does not exist'
W/ReactNativeJS(18572): 'Warning: Native component for "RCTTextField" does not exist'
D/ReactNativeJS(18572): 'Running application "velib" with appParams: {"initialProps":{},"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Maps for android haven't been open sourced in the initial android release. There's a list of views and modules that will be open sourced over time [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#views).

Comment: Oh… right. So, the right answer is "wait until it'll be open sourced" ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I am running a blank project and have 
Warning: Native component for "RCTMap" does not exist
Warning: Native component for "RCTModalHostView" does not exist
Warning: Native component for "RCTWebView" does not exist
what is this?