# Warning: Native component for "RCTMap" does not exist

Tags: android, dictionary, react-native, android-mapview

My App does not show map.

I have an error when i activate debug console.

My Virtual Device

Genymotion

Google Nexus 7 5.0 API 21

By the way I tried my Samsung s4 device but dont work with the same error.

[image]

```
/* @flow */
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');

var {
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  MapView,
  AppRegistry
} = React;

var Harita = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <MapView
        style={styles.map} />
    );
  }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    map: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
    }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('harita', () => Harita);
```

Comment: i'm getting the same problem.
[Emulator error.](http://i.imgur.com/X60YRVT.png)
[Code snippet.](http://i.imgur.com/hrEyN5E.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No view Manager defined for class RCTMap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32625259/no-view-manager-defined-for-class-rctmap)

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to add definition that you are using Map Services and API key which is required otherwise you'll see an empty screen.

Add this to your androidmanifest (before application element ending)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Facebook hasn't provided the Android version of MapView in the open source version of React Native. As noted [here](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/known-issues.html#views), you can "use Leland Richardson's [react-native-maps](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-maps) as it is more feature-complete than our internal implementation."